# How to check if one table field is null select data from other table field and orderby it

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, model

I have two tables 1(Attendance) and 2(Attendance_correction) I am querying this to get attendance in asc order using time field:

```
foreach ($employee_calendars as $key => $employee_calendar) {
        $employee_calendar->attendance = Attendance::where("employee_id", $employee->id)
            ->whereDate("date", "=", $employee_calendar->date)
            ->orderBy('time', 'asc')
            ->with("requests")
            ->get();
    }
```

problem is that when time field in my attendance table is null it puts this data on top of response, in the case of null I want to check if there is any attendance correction of this attendance check correct_time field in attendance_correction instead of attendance time field following are my table pictures with highlighted rows, I also have relation in attendance table (requests) for attendance_correction table:

```
public function requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\AttendanceCorrection", "attendance_id");
}
```

[attendance_correction Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/604KU.png)

[attendance table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtZ2B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Attendance::select(['*', \DB::raw('IF(`time` IS NOT NULL, `time`, `attendance_correction.correct_time`) `correctTime`')])
->join->on('attendance_corrrection.attendence_id', '=', 'attendance.id');
        ->where("employee_id", $employee->id)
        ->whereDate("date", "=", $employee_calendar->date)
        ->orderBy('correctTime', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: wait let me try it.

Comment: it is giving me error : 
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;attendance_correction.correct_time&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: select *, IF(`time` IS NOT NULL, `time`, `attendance_correction`.correct_time) `correctTime` from `attendance` where `employee_id` = 47 and date(`date`) = 2022-05-18 order by `correctTime` asc) in file /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 669

Comment: Then instead of with can you do join, like this?  ->join->on('attendence_corrrection.attendence_id', '=', 'attendence..id');
    })

Comment: I have tried join but it only shows the attendance which has attendance_correction else is not showing:

Attendance::join("attendance_corrections", "attendance.id", "=", "attendance_corrections.attendance_id")
            ->select(['*', \DB::raw('IF(`time` IS NOT NULL, `time`, attendance_corrections.correct_time) `correctTime`')])
                ->where("attendance.employee_id", $employee->id)
                ->whereDate("attendance.date", "=", $employee_calendar->date)
                ->orderBy('correctTime', 'asc')
                ->with("requests")
                ->get();

Comment: Please check with right or left join.

Comment: yeah have tried it but not giving required results.